# How to use Link Source in eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have Android and pure java projects. I want to use code from pure java project inside Android - how should I use Link Source option to do this? I don't want "projects" tab inside java build path because it sometimes does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choice one:

1. Export your java to .jar file.
2. Copy the .jar file to the libs folder under the android project with eclipse.

Choice two : 
Just copy the code to your android project.

Comment: For now the adt tools needs you copy the jar file into the libs folder.it will link it automatic for you.  "java build path" -> "source doesn't work with the latest adt.

Comment: ?? Link source has always worked for me, and I find it much preferable to using library projects.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#SettingUpLibraryProject).  Create an Android project in eclipse with the source code.  Mark it as a library project and other Android projects will be able to add the library project to their dependencies.

Comment: Pure java projects can't be checked as "library project". AFAIK this is only available in Android world.